# Controling the animated scroll rate in a UIScrollview - IOS development

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, rate

I've implemented some code, which is working nicely, to scroll a UIScrollview automatically based on a timer being triggered.

Here  it is:

```
....
CGPoint offset;
....
offset = scroller.contentOffset;
....
- (void) scrollWords: (NSTimer *) theTimer
{
offset.y = offset.y+300;
[UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
[UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:50.0f];
[scroller  setContentOffset:offset];
[UIScrollView commitAnimations];

}
```

However, I've noticed that the while the scrolling is happening, the scroll rate varies; half way through it scrolls 2 or 3 lines of text per second, but at the start and finish it's much slower, perhaps only 0.5 lines per second. Is there any way of controlling the scroll rate?

Thanks in advance.

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `setAnimationCurve:`. Specifically what you're describing is the effect of `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`. Try adding `[UIScrollView setAnimationCurve:UIAnimationCurveLinear];`

Also, you're using old style animation code. If you're targeting iOS 4 or above, check out this new style that's much more friendly (in my opinion):

```
- (void) scrollWords: (NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    offset.y = offset.y+300;
    [UIScrollView animateWithDuration:50.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [scroller setContentOffset:offset];
    }];
}
```

Using the delay parameter, you can probably even get rid of your NSTimer. With this code you can scroll the table view after 5 seconds.

```
- (void) scrollWordsLater
{
    offset.y = offset.y+300;
    [UIScrollView animateWithDuration:50.0f delay:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [scroller setContentOffset:offset];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Great response. Thanks!!! I'm not seeing any different using the different animationCurves, so I switched to using your code sample. There seems to be an issue tho, which I can't resolve: I'm getting this error msg:" No known class method for 'animateWithDuration: Delay : options: animations:' "

Comment: Looks like I left out the 'completion:NULL' part! works nicely now! :) Thanks!